# Setting MFA phone number for a user AAD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity, multi-factor-authentication

I'm trying to set a phone number for a user for MFA:

[image]

This gives me the error:

> "Partial failure in authentication methods update Unable to update
>   phone methods for user"

Why is that? The phone number is still stored. Am I correct the number in the field is stored into `strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber` property which cannot be read?

Comment: Please check the similar [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/53341) which may help your issue.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there is something wrong with this feature in Azure Portal currently and it also exists in Azure AD (Not just in B2C).

If you are using admin account which is a guest user, the backend will give an error: 401 Unauthorized. But the update will be successful.

If a normal admin account is used, the update will be successful without any errors.